# Client-side caching of static files not working (Apache)

Tags: apache, caching, browser-cache

I'm trying to use `mod_expires` and `mod_headers` to enable browser caching for my site. I have this in my VirtualHost:

```
    <FilesMatch ".(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf|js|css|pdf)$">
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
        Header unset Last-Modified
    </FilesMatch>
```

The `Expires` and `Cache-Control` headers are set correctly in my responses:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 28 Jun 2016 16:09:26 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
ETag: "8f44-526a1625962b5-gzip"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Cache-Control: public
Expires: Tue, 05 Jul 2016 16:09:26 GMT
Content-Length: 8504
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/javascript
```

Unfortunately, my browser (Chrome) is still requesting all these static files every time I load [my page](http://delfsail.ookmijnbedrijf.nl). I see these requests in my `access.log` and browser console. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I do have caching enabled in the developer toolbar:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if client-side caching is disabled. Google Chrome [may disable client-side caching](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/settings) when the [DevTools window](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) is open (F12).

[image: Chrome Devtools]

Comment: Good tip, I do have caching enabled though. Updated question.

Comment: How do other browsers handle the files? Are they ignoring the cache as well?

Comment: Firefox is also ignoring my headers. Meanwhile, it's caching files from other sites requested by the same [page](http://delfsail.ookmijnbedrijf.nl/).